# How to make website with twitter bootstrap that will focus on currently viewed div?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to achieve something like [this example](http://www.myprovence.fr/#p_partnerships).

This single page website keeps current view while resizing.
For example, if I am reading  the section : `#p_partnerships`  while resizing browser window it will still show the content of `#p_partnerships`.

I have modified some [single page bootstrap template](http://untame.net/2013/01/how-to-design-a-single-page-scrolling-site-with-twitter-bootstrap/).

It works like a charm, but when I am resizing it, it does behave like any other scrollable page. I mean to get back to the section that was visible before resizing I have to click on some link and then on that section's link again. I don't care about mouse scroll effect from myprovence all I need is to keep the top of currently viewed section right below the navigation bar.

Here is some bits and pieces of what I've got:

In addition to *jQuery ScrollTo,* my template uses *jQuery One Page Nav Plugin*

```
;(function($, window, document, undefined){

// our plugin constructor
var OnePageNav = function(elem, options){
this.elem = elem;
this.$elem = $(elem);
this.options = options;
this.metadata = this.$elem.data('plugin-options');
this.$nav = this.$elem.find('a');
this.$win = $(window);
this.sections = {};
this.didScroll = false;
this.$doc = $(document);
this.docHeight = this.$doc.height();
};

// the plugin prototype
OnePageNav.prototype = {
defaults: {
currentClass: 'current',
changeHash: false,
easing: 'swing',
filter: '',
scrollSpeed: 750,
scrollOffset: 0,
scrollThreshold: 0.5,
begin: false,
end: false,
scrollChange: false
},

init: function() {
var self = this;

// Introduce defaults that can be extended either
// globally or using an object literal.
self.config = $.extend({}, self.defaults, self.options, self.metadata);

//Filter any links out of the nav
if(self.config.filter !== '') {
self.$nav = self.$nav.filter(self.config.filter);
}

//Handle clicks on the nav
self.$nav.on('click.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.handleClick, self));

//Get the section positions
self.getPositions();

//Handle scroll changes
self.bindInterval();

//Update the positions on resize too
self.$win.on('resize.onePageNav', $.proxy(self.getPositions, self));

eturn this;
},
adjustNav: function(self, $parent) {
self.$elem.find('.' + self.config.currentClass).removeClass(self.config.currentClass);
$parent.addClass(self.config.currentClass);
},

bindInterval: function() {
var self = this;
var docHeight;

self.$win.on('scroll.onePageNav', function() {
self.didScroll = true;
});

self.t = setInterval(function() {
docHeight = self.$doc.height();

//If it was scrolled
if(self.didScroll) {
self.didScroll = false;
self.scrollChange();
}

//If the document height changes
if(docHeight !== self.docHeight) {
self.docHeight = docHeight;
self.getPositions();
}
}, 250);
},

getHash: function($link) {
return $link.attr('href').split('#')[1];
},

getPositions: function() {
var self = this;
var linkHref;
var topPos;
var $target;

self.$nav.each(function() {
linkHref = self.getHash($(this));
$target = $('#' + linkHref);

if($target.length) {
topPos = $target.offset().top;
self.sections[linkHref] = Math.round(topPos) - self.config.scrollOffset;
}
});
},

getSection: function(windowPos) {
var returnValue = null;
var windowHeight = Math.round(this.$win.height() * this.config.scrollThreshold);

for(var section in this.sections) {
if((this.sections[section] - windowHeight) < windowPos) {
returnValue = section;
}
}

return returnValue;
},

handleClick: function(e) {
var self = this;
var $link = $(e.currentTarget);
var $parent = $link.parent();
var newLoc = '#' + self.getHash($link);

if(!$parent.hasClass(self.config.currentClass)) {
//Start callback
if(self.config.begin) {
self.config.begin();
}

//Change the highlighted nav item
self.adjustNav(self, $parent);

//Removing the auto-adjust on scroll
self.unbindInterval();

//Scroll to the correct position
$.scrollTo(newLoc, self.config.scrollSpeed, {
axis: 'y',
easing: self.config.easing,
offset: {
top: -self.config.scrollOffset
},
onAfter: function() {
//Do we need to change the hash?
if(self.config.changeHash) {
window.location.hash = newLoc;
}

//Add the auto-adjust on scroll back in
self.bindInterval();

//End callback
if(self.config.end) {
self.config.end();
}
}
});
}
e.preventDefault();
},

scrollChange: function() {
var windowTop = this.$win.scrollTop();
var position = this.getSection(windowTop);
var $parent;

//If the position is set
if(position !== null) {
$parent = this.$elem.find('a[href$="#' + position + '"]').parent();

//If it's not already the current section
if(!$parent.hasClass(this.config.currentClass)) {
//Change the highlighted nav item
this.adjustNav(this, $parent);

//If there is a scrollChange callback
if(this.config.scrollChange) {
this.config.scrollChange($parent);
}
}
}
},

unbindInterval: function() {
clearInterval(this.t);
this.$win.unbind('scroll.onePageNav');
}
};

OnePageNav.defaults = OnePageNav.prototype.defaults;


$.fn.onePageNav = function(options) {

return this.each(function() {
new OnePageNav(this, options).init();
});
};

})( jQuery, window , document );
```

In html document I have this bit:

```
<script>
$('#top-nav').onePageNav({
currentClass: 'active',
changeHash: true,
scrollSpeed: 1200
});

</script>
```

I've tried a piece of code suggested by Alexander but it does not work for me.

the first part:

```
<script>
function goToByScroll(id){
$('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top}, 2000);
}
</script>
```

does work with links like this

```
<a href="#" onClick="goToByScroll('#section-2')">
```

But this is the same thing that I already have.

I have experimented with something like this

```
$(window).on("resize", function () {
goToByScroll('#section-2')
```

It does scroll to top of the `#section-two` every time I resize the browser.

Need some solution to scroll to currently viewed section and not always to the same `#section-2`

Answer (score 0):

You need two things to make this work:  A function that scrolls to a div, and a listener to know when someone has scrolled.

First, a jQuery function that can scroll to your divs.  You can use something similar to this:

```
function goToByScroll(id){
  $('html, body').stop().animate({scrollTop: $(id).offset().top}, 2000);
}
```

See [Jquery - scroll to div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853517/jquery-scroll-to-div), or search Stackoverflow for more information.
And then you need to know when you're scrolling.  You can use jQuery for this, and then call the function goToByScroll()

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop){
    // downscroll code
    goToByScroll(next_page_id);
  } else {
    // upscroll code
    goToByScroll(last_page_id);
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

See [How can I determine the direction of a jQuery scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326845/how-can-i-determine-the-direction-of-a-jquery-scroll-event)  That should be enough to get you a good start.  You'd just have to keep track of what page you're on, and what page is next if you scroll up or down.